# React inject JSX template from server for custom components

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, material-ui, server-side-rendering

We have build React App with our own component library mixed with Material Ui components.
Our goal is to provide customizations for different customers for the React App. Idea is to provide custom views with when calling API endpoints. Like /fetch/customer_view/:ID.

The question is how we should inject the custom jsx views from server. For example Material Ui Dialog with specific layout(Components are in react build). Backend is built with python.

Example JSX we want to load:

```
<Container>
   <Header>Hello world</Header>
   <Typography>This is layout is loaded from server</Typography>
</Container>
```